# How to use SphericalPlot3D in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I’m learning how to use SphericalPlot3D. I’m using the following statement:

```
SphericalPlot3D[Cos[θ],{θ,0,π},{ɸ,0,2 π}]
```

I was expecting to get a cosine curve along y-axis rotated around the same axis. More or less like an hourglass. What I get is a sphere. What do I have to specify in SphericalPlot3D in order to get rotated vertical cosine?

When I use the following statement:

```
SphericalPlot3D[Cos[2 θ],{θ,0,π},{ɸ,0,2 π}]
```

I would expect to get 2 hourglasses, one standing on the other along y-axis. I get something different. Where do I go wrong?

Thanks/Mikael

Comment: the first argument is the spherical coordinate radius form the origin.  Note in both cases your radius is negative (so invalid)  for part of the domain, i assume mathematica just ignores that part.

Comment: Yes, now I'm squaring radius function, it works better but goes wrong with radius function square(cos(2 theta)). However function SphericalHarmonicY available in Mathematica returns correct function that can be plotted after squaring.

Comment: I was wrong above, a negative radius is valid and simply projects the surface in the opposite direction.  Suggest if you want to make surfaces of revolution you work with `PolarPlot` to get the figure you want, then convert to `SphericalPlot3D`

Answer (score 1):

I guess, what you wanted is a surface or revolution with a cosine shape rotated about one axis to get a Hourglass. It is more a Cylindrical plot. The Spherical Plot more or less bends the top and bottom together to form a kind of sphere.
My solution for your problem would be:

```
RevolutionPlot3D[{Cos[t], t}, {t, 0, π}, {ɸ, 0, 2 π}]
```

which gives the following plot:

[image: Surface of Revolution for Cos(t)]

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bit late, but a friend of mine just had the same problem so I thought I'd document the solution somewhere.

The confusion comes from the way in which Mathematica defines θ and φ. In most cases they're defined as follows:

[image: Spherical Coordinates]

However, Mathematica actually defines θ as what you think should be φ and φ as what you think should be θ for some reason. The following screenshot is taken from the [documentation page](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SphericalPlot3D.html) for SphericalPlot3D explaining these definitions.

[image: SphericalPlot3D Documentation Page]

A simple fix to this is to swap the way you define the variables when calling SphericalPlot3D. So instead of writing

```
SphericalPlot3D[Cos[2 θ],{θ,0,π},{ɸ,0,2 π}]
```

You would want to write:

```
SphericalPlot3D[Cos[2 θ],{ɸ,0,2 π},{θ,0,π}]
```